# Make Filtering for Codeigniter Login

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, authentication

I have a Login system in my CodeIgniter project. But, I want to make some condition filtering like this :

**If `username` not `admin` then go back to login page**

Here's my Model script :

```
  //Get Data Login
public function getAllData($table)
{
    return $this->db->get($table)->result();
}

function login($username, $password) {
    //create query to connect user login database
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('artist');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);

    //get query and processing
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result(); //if data is true
    } else {
        return false; //if data is wrong
    }
}
```

And on every Controller I have:

```
    function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_admin_data');
    $this->load->helper(array('url'));


    //CEK LOGIN
    if($this->session->userdata('login_status') != TRUE ){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('notif','Login Gagal!! Username atau Password Salah !');
        redirect('Admin_login');
    };
     $this->load->model('m_admin_data');

    // END CEK LOGIN
}
```

Can anybody please help me do this? 
only `username` == `admin` can access this page

and this for View files :

```html
<form class="form-signin form-horizontal m-t-20" action="<?= site_url('Admin_login/cek_login')?>" method="post">
  <!-- NOTIF -->
  <?php
            $message = $this->session->flashdata('notif');
            if($message){
                echo '<p class="alert alert-success text-center">'.$message .'</p>';
            }?>

    <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group text-center m-t-30">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class="btn btn-custom btn-bordred btn-block waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group m-t-30 m-b-0">

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where and how r u  posting login form data?

Answer (score 1):

I Think you will be better served defining those condition on hooks. Use `pre_controller` hooks. Then, you won't have to declare condition on each controller.

If the condition on the hooks is not met, then you just need to redirect to login page. In the `pre_controller` hooks, skip checking the login condition on login page.

[Hooks Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html?highlight=hooks)

Comment: what if in Model I make  condition like this 
  if($query->num_rows() == 1 and $username ="admin") can it possible to pu AND in that section ?

Comment: Same difference, rather than persisting on checking if username is admin, why not just check if the user is **logged in** and then on some controller that allow only admin, check if the logged in user is currently and admin. Maybe breaking down your logical case to smaller bits will help you see the data flow.

Comment: While providing full script is out of question. I think you could use reference on this article https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-codeigniter-hook-system-works--cms-29301 Try to play around by assigning session on hooks. I haven't used CI for more than a year now. But their script flow is pretty straightforward. Some question about authentication login on hooks been asked here before, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `MY_Controller.php` in `application/core` and have your controllers where you want this logic to be applied extend `MY_Controller` rather than `CI_Controller`

Example `MY_Controller`:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('auth_model', 'auth');
        if (!$this->auth->is_logged()) {
            redirect('login');
        }
        if (!$this->auth->is_admin()) {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }

}
```

You should **not** use `MY_Controller` for the login controller or you will end up in an infinite redirect loop; so this is only really for protected pages. You can also call it something else and even have different core controllers using requires.

That being said I'm not sure why you are allowing login for non-admins if all you are going to do is redirect them to the login page.

---

***Also `md5()` is not a secure way of hashing passwords. Even php says so.***

Answer (score 1):

Would you please add one more where statement in your function see below

```
function do_validate() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        # not allowed, display error message
        $this->load->view('myform');
    }
    else
    {   
        # success
        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        if(login($username, $password)) {
            # redirect page after login
        } else {
            # show error message
        }
    }
}

public function username_check($str){
    if ($str != 'admin'){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'Only admin login allowed');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

function login($username, $password) {
    //create query to connect user login database
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('artist');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', MD5($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);

    //get query and processing
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result(); //if data is true
    } else {
        return false; //if data is wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry can you explain more about this code , still dont understand in part Where clause,, I want to filtering , so only people with username "admin" can entering

Comment: Hello @RiandyEka Please check the updated answer.

You can do it without your login function but i have done it with your function for better understanding

Comment: You need to call do_validate() when your form is submitted.

Comment: Can you check again to my thread , I've edit and Add my View Files named "v_admin_login.php"

Comment: Yes, you can edit your form action in view file and call do_validate function in form action. Try it, it will work for you!!

Comment: and how call do_validate I mean what the proper structure syntax gonna be ?

Comment: Its too simple dear, I have already mentioned it in the above comment. You have to call the do_validate function in the form action.

Comment: so I call do_validate in "view" file right ? or ion controller file  ?

Comment: Yes, in the view file. see like <form class="form-signin form-horizontal m-t-20" action="<?= site_url('{controller_name}/do_validate')?>" method="post">

Comment: yes but I already have function cek_login() that you can see ?

Comment: Yes dear but something you have to change in your code if don't need to change function name then see my code and put it in your function only.